# Two sides of cube are not baking normal correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I am trying to create round edges on cube using normal, and it works nicely, except I'm having issues with some sides that are not baking at all, as well as black seams. What could be causing this?

Setup:

Low poly - Smoothed, edge split

High poly - Rounded corners, smoothed - expanded to cover low poly

Cage - Low poly clone, expanded to cover everything

Baking in cycles. 
[image]
[image]